# Как соединить несколько строк в одну?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

В текстовом файле расположены строки в таком виде:

```
>>>
Stroka1
Stroka2
Stroka3
>>>
>>>
Stroka4
Stroka5
Stroka6
Stroka7
>>>
```

Как соединить строки что между символами **>>>** в одну и между ними поставить точку. То есть результат должен получится:

```
>>>
Stroka1.Stroka2.Stroka3
>>>
>>>
Stroka4.Stroka5.Stroka6.Stroka7
>>>
```

Читала про функцию (Но я так понимаю что это идет соединение по ключевым словам):

```
result := Concat('Stroka1','Stroka2','Stroka3');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант (если файл не гигантский)...

```
var
  ts: TStringList;
   s: string;

...
ts := TStringList.Create();
try
  ts.LoadFromFile( 'c:\temp\lines.txt' );
  s := StringReplace( ts.Text, ts.LineBreak, '.', [ rfReplaceAll ] );
  s := StringReplace( s, '>>>.', '>>>' + ts.LineBreak, [ rfReplaceAll ] );
  s := StringReplace( s, '.>>>', ts.LineBreak + '>>>', [ rfReplaceAll ] );
  ts.Text := s;
  ts.SaveToFile( 'c:\temp\lines-new.txt' );
finally
  ts.Free();
end;
...
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает как и нужно было!

Answer (score 2):

Простейший алгоритм же:

1. Читаем файл построчно
2. Если видим строчку, то дописываем её во временную переменную, через "точку"
3. Если видим разделитель, то записываем в новый файл переменную из п.2 и записываем разделитель, и очищаем временную переменную.
4. Остальные действия (начало или конец файла без разделителей, и т.п.) - по вкусу

---

Как соединять?

```
uses StrUtils;
...
s := s + IfThen(s <> '', '.') + newText;
```

Comment: Я так понимаю что newText это следующая строка. Количество строк в столбике может быть разным между >>>. Как тогда быть ?

Comment: Для каждой строки - не разделителя - это делаете, таким образом собирая строку для вывода